# How would I best and safely wire a parent/children objects together

Tags: php, immutability

This is my demonstration case:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

final class Order
{
    /** @var array|OrderPosition[] */
    private $orderPositions;

    public static function fromArray($orderData)
    {
        assert(isset($orderData['orderId']));
        assert(isset($orderData['positions']));

        return
            new self(
                $orderData['orderId'],
                array_map(
                    function (array $positionData): OrderPosition {
                        // I would like to put the "future self (Order)" alread here
                        return OrderPosition::fromArray($positionData);
                    },
                    $orderData['positions']
                )
            );
    }

    private function __construct(string $orderId, array $orderPositions)
    {
        $this->orderPositions = $orderPositions;
        // what I want to avoid is:
        array_walk($orderPositions, function (OrderPosition $position) {
            $position->defineOwningOrder($this);
        });
    }
}

final class OrderPosition
{
    /** @var Order */
    private $owningOrder;

    public static function fromArray($positionData /* + as mentioned I'd like to put the "calling" Order here already...? */)
    {
        return
            new self(
                $positionData['productId'],
                $positionData['amount']
            );
    }

    private function __construct(string $productId, int $amount)
    {
        // …
    }

    /** @internal */
    public function defineOwningOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $this->owningOrder = $order;
    }
}
```

I like to have a pointer to the "parent"/owning Order item in my OrderPosition; however since Order is considered an Aggregate Root I want Order to be in charge of creating the collection of OrderPositions.

How should I put the Order item in every OrderPosition when the final Order is not yet there on creation?
My current approach is to late-set it in Order's ctor but that would mutate OrderPosition, strictly spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a combination of several design decisions here which are in conflict:

1. immutable objects
2. a circular reference
3. a constructor which is not responsible for constructing the dependent objects
4. a factory method which is not allowed to see and mutate a partial object

As you say, your current implementation compromises on (1) by allowing the `OrderPosition` to have the extra reference added in later.

You can make the problem go away if you remove (2). What is the situation where you would have a reference to an `OrderPosition` and want to navigate to the `Order` to which it belongs? Can that situation be re-framed as a responsibility of the `Order`, removing the circular reference?

You could change (3) such that the constructor took the information to create `OrderPositions`, not the `OrderPositions` themselves. In your example, this would be trivial, but if in practise you have a number of different factories feeding into one constructor, this might become messy.

Alternatively, if you relax (4) you could pass the partially constructed object into the `OrderPosition` constructor / factory:

```
public static function fromArray($orderData)
{
    assert(isset($orderData['orderId']));
    assert(isset($orderData['positions']));

    $instance = new self($orderData['orderId']);
    foreach ( $orderData['positions'] as $positionData ) {
        $instance->orderPositions[] = OrderPosition::fromArray($positionData, $instance);
    }
    return $instance;
}
```

While this still looks like mutation, it is only the same mutation you would do in any constructor - you are creating the initial state of the object.

In a language that supported overloaded or named constructors, `fromArray` would *be* a constructor, and might not share any implementation with other constructors. In PHP, you can emulate that pattern with an empty `private function __construct(){}` and static methods starting with `$instance = new self;`

Comment: what a spectacular answer, thank you! I'll go for (4), that's exactly my way to go.